# BlogEngine: Access to the path blog\App_Data\users.xm is denied

Tags: asp.net, .net, blogengine.net

I have configured BlogEngine in /blog directory of my site, I am able to post blogs but can't change password see the error trace below. Any help would be appreciated.

I have given write permissions to NETWORK Service on Custom and APP_Data folders but it didn't solve my issue.

```
Server Error in '/blog' Application.
Access to the path 'c:\HostingSpaces\abc\def.com\wwwroot\blog\App_Data\users.xml' is denied.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\HostingSpaces\abc\def.com\wwwroot\blog\App_Data\users.xml' is denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\HostingSpaces\hypv8417\def.com\wwwroot\blog\App_Data\users.xml' is denied.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +216
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1430
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +205
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +87
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename) +205
   BlogEngine.Core.Providers.XmlMembershipProvider.ChangePassword(String username, String oldPassword, String newPassword) +472
   System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.ChangePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) +213
   System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.ChangePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword, Boolean throwOnError) +33
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ChangePassword.AttemptChangePassword() +329
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ChangePassword.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +107
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +84
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change password application has to have write permission. By default that is not the case.

I would recommend temp solution:

Set write permission for user/group IIS_IUSRS to file 
c:\HostingSpaces\abc\def.com\wwwroot\blog\App_Data\users.xml .

Change password via website.

Remove write permission from the file.