# BlogEngine.NET - New Users / Change Password

Tags: .net, xml, blogengine.net

We are currently running the BlogEngine.NET blogging system on our website - version 2.9.1.0 but are struggling to add new users and changing / resetting account passwords.

Initially, we were convinced it was related to read / write permissions to the App_Data folder but we are able to update existing account details.

When trying to add a new user on BlogEngine.NET, we receive the below "toast" notification message: [Toast Notification (screen grab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dINEw.png)

Google Chrome's Developer Tools console shows an error for POST "/blog/api/users" 500 Internal Server Error and makes reference to the angular.min.js file (we are using AngularJS v1.2.2, that came as part of this version of BlogEngine.NET by default).

When trying to reset a user password on BlogEngine.NET, we receive the following .NET error message: [.NET Runtime Error (screen grab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdWAD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application does need read/write permission in order to create users.

See: https://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/how-to-create-an-authentication-provider-for-ftp-7-5-using-blogengine-net-s-xml-membership-files

And: [BlogEngine: Access to the path blog\App_Data\users.xm is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208678/blogengine-access-to-the-path-blog-app-data-users-xm-is-denied)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Vakore.

Comment: I've updated the permissions on the users.xml file but I'm still experiencing the same error message. I may start my blog setup from scratch and try again!!

Comment: Hi Vakore, yes - I've re-installed the blog on our website but still coming up with the same error (error adding new user)!

Comment: We have recently installed a HTTPS certificate on the website with the URL rewrite module - could this be the cause of the issues?

Comment: It could be, but I'm not sure. I'll do some research on that later today.

Comment: Hi Vakore, did you manage to have a look into the issue? I've tried full re-installations, read / write access for various users but nothing seems to work! Thanks in advance

Comment: I've been trying to do some research, and right now I'm getting nowhere. Can you please give me a little more to go off of?(Do this by editting your question please so that the comments don't overflow?)                Also, here is this link if it is of any help: https://forums.asp.net/t/1576004.aspx?Change+Password+in+BlogEngine+v1+6    I assure you, I am trying the best I can. Some more info should help.

Comment: Thanks Vakore - question updated (last comment, I promise!!)

Comment: I don't know the issue. My deepest apologies, but I am stumped. It could be an error deep in your code, but I can't figure it out. Again, my deepest apologies. My advice is ask on different sites and hope for the best.

Comment: No problem Vakore - thanks for your help!

I think I'm going to replace the BlogEngine.NET system with it's successor which looks to be called Miniblog (https://github.com/madskristensen/MiniBlog)!